# Could not able to deploy my rails project after Heroku-18 stack upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5.2

While deploying i am getting this error. Upgraded rails to 5.2 and ruby to 2.5.1 after that while upgrading heroku stack i am getting the same erorr.
Anyone have answer for this please?

```
remote:        
remote:        Bundle completed (259.65s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
remote:        Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
remote: -----> Detecting rails configuration
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found.


remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1032:in `retrieve_connection'
    remote:  !     

/tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:118:in `retrieve_connection'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:90:in `connection'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:466:in `load_schema!'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/attributes.rb:234:in `load_schema!'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:51:in `load_schema!'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:459:in `block in load_schema'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:456:in `load_schema'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:336:in `columns_hash'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `block in valid?'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `all?'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:60:in `valid?'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:11:in `respond_to_missing?'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:205:in `respond_to?'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:205:in `valid_scope_name?'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.1/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb:180:in `scope'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/si-core_data-3.0.6/lib/si/core_data/user_service/user.rb:14:in `<class:User>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/si-core_data-3.0.6/lib/si/core_data/user_service/user.rb:4:in `<module:UserService>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/si-core_data-3.0.6/lib/si/core_data/user_service/user.rb:2:in `<module:SI>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/si-core_data-3.0.6/lib/si/core_data/user_service/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/si-core_data-3.0.6/lib/si/core_data/user_service.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/si-core_data-3.0.6/lib/si/core_data.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:95:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:95:in `rescue in block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Caused by:
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- si-core_data
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_8941f32f57c79f59e7ea337d348ba6f8/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
```

Comment: This is the interesting part: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found.` How do you configure your database connection on Heroku (`database.yml` or via `ENV` variable)? How it configured?

Comment: @spickermann Yes I have used environment variable for making database connection.

Comment: And how is that ENV variable named? And how is the value structured? The reason I am asking is that I wonder why the error message tells that some database config is missing for `primary` and `primary` is not part of the default database configuration naming in Rails 5.2

Comment: @spickermann     It is like this:-
DATABASE_URL    postgresql://project_name:key
I think it is related to asets or rakes. It is saying Could not detect rake tasks

Comment: @spickermann The project is running on my local system, but I am not able to deploy it on heroku.

Comment: can you please post your `database.yml` file.

Comment: Can you share the last lines of the `Gemfile.lock` file? Specifically where it says: `RUBY VERSION` and `BUNDLED WITH`

Comment: Post your database.yml or show us the config for production

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before, I think this is caused by your bundler version. Your local system runs the current version of bundler fine, heroku does not.

Try this locally:

```
gem install bundler -v 2.0.2
bundle update --bundler
```

and deploy that to heroku and see if it helps.

Comment: @Sachin I would try to upgrade ruby to 2.5.5+ as a next step and try again. If that is not an option, I would try the same steps I have in this answer with `bundler -v 2.0.1`

Comment: My current ruby version is 2.5.1 also tried it with ruby version 2.5.7 but that too not worked.

Comment: I know, I recommend you try and upgrade ruby to 2.5.5+, or lower your bundler version to 2.0.1. There is a bug in ruby-gems that requires bundler to be the exact same version pre-2.2.5. Checking your buildpack, the bundler version should be 2.0.1 if I'm not mistaken.

so 
`gem uninstall bundler;gem install bundler --version '2.0.1';bundle update --bundler;`
Should work. But, I recommend updating ruby instead if possible

Comment: Fair enough, I can't think of anything else I'd try unfortunately. Good luck with your question!